# error of grails project from svn : GroovyObject cannot be resolved

Tags: eclipse, svn, grails

when i check out a new grails project from svn, i got some error:

> 1.The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find
>   the class file for
>   groovy.lang.GroovyObject. Fix the
>   build path then try building this
>   project
>
> 2.The type groovy.lang.GroovyObject cannot be resolved. It is indirectly
>   referenced from required .class files

i had config the grails path, and it can run-app well.  but,still error warning.

[image]

Comment: Is this a IDE problem? Which are u using? Which version? STS?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Solved by "grails tool -> refresh dependencies"

Comment: sometime, it needs to restart sts... seem to be a ide bug

Answer (score 14):

I ran into the same error and fixed it by adding the Groovy runtime libraries to the build path:

Configure Build Path -> Libraries -> Add Library -> Groovy Runtime Libraries.

Not using STS.

Answer (score 1):

We have to set Groovy Compiler in Eclipse for specific project.
1. Eclipse -> Windows -> Preference -> Search Groovy Compiler.
2. Click on Configure Project Specific Setting.
3. Select Your Project.
4. Will Open Groovy Compiler Wizard. 
5. Set Compiler level for this project.
6. Apply and close it.
7. Now All groovy Jar file will download and build will get success.

it worked for me.
Hope this answer will help.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure there are no errors in the "Problems Tab". Until and unless you clear these errors, you will not be able to resolve this error.

Run "Refresh Dependencies" and make sure all the required dependencies are properly downloaded.